# Having issue with my Select Case, output not working

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT date,
       (CASE country WHEN 'France' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS france,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Germany' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS germany,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Italy' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS italy,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Netherlands' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS netherlands,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Nordic' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS nordic,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Spain' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS spain,
       (CASE country WHEN 'UK' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS uk
FROM report_adherence_daily
WHERE date>= '2016-07-04'
  AND date<= '2016-07-10'
GROUP BY date,
         country
```

Above is my code to transpose data into the format that I need but the result is  showing as

[image: Result of the query].

What I am missing is the extra bit that makes the results look like

[image: Required Result].

I have tried to use max before the case and within the case and that hasn't worked. If I group by Date only, I'm missing most of my data which is the same as Grouping by Country. What am I missing?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Ho does it look if you just group by Date

Comment: Date France Germany Italy Netherlands Nordic Spain UK
04/07/2016 0 0 0 0 0 0 64.6687
05/07/2016 0 0 0 0 0 0 65.5704
06/07/2016 0 0 0 0 0 0 66.4563
07/07/2016 0 0 0 0 0 0 69.797
08/07/2016 65.656 0 0 0 0 0 0
09/07/2016 81.5008 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: The result for the Date grouping is the comment above. I am currently using phpMyAdmin database and will eventually have the code in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have already hardcoded the country names so this isn't so bad......

```
SELECT 
  Date, 
  Sum(France) as France, 
  Sum(Germany) as Germany,
  Sum(Italy) as Italy,
  Sum(Netherlands) as Netherlands,
  Sum(Nordic) as Nordic,
  Sum(Spain) as Spain,
  Sum(Uk) as UK
FROM
(
SELECT date,
       (CASE country WHEN 'France' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS france,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Germany' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS germany,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Italy' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS italy,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Netherlands' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS netherlands,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Nordic' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS nordic,
       (CASE country WHEN 'Spain' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS spain,
       (CASE country WHEN 'UK' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS uk
FROM report_adherence_daily
WHERE date>= '2016-07-04'
  AND date<= '2016-07-10'
GROUP BY date,
         country
)SUB_Q
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Works a dream AntDC. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You want conditional aggregation, but the `case` needs to go inside the `sum()`, not outside it:

```
SELECT date,
       (100 * sum(case when country = 'France' then duration end) /
        sum(case when country = 'France' then scheduled end)
       ) as france,
       . . .
FROM report_adherence_daily
WHERE date >= '2016-07-04' AND date <= '2016-07-10'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Works Gordon. Thanks for your help on this. Have null value now though??

Comment: If you have a `NULL` value, it means that a country does not have data on that date.  You have to figure out what to do, in that case.  For instance, if there is no `duration`, you could add `else 0` to the first `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a subquery then?

```
SELECT date, MAX(france), MAX(germany), MAX(italy), MAX(netherlands), MAX(Nordic), MAX(spain)
FROM 
   (
       SELECT date,
           (CASE country WHEN 'France' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS france,
           (CASE country WHEN 'Germany' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS germany,
           (CASE country WHEN 'Italy' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS italy,
           (CASE country WHEN 'Netherlands' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS netherlands,
           (CASE country WHEN 'Nordic' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS nordic,
           (CASE country WHEN 'Spain' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS spain,
           (CASE country WHEN 'UK' THEN (sum(duration) / sum(scheduled))*100 ELSE 0 END) AS uk
       FROM report_adherence_daily
       WHERE date>= '2016-07-04'
         AND date<= '2016-07-10'
       GROUP BY date,
                country
   )
GROUP BY date
```

I haven't used mySql for a while and I can't test it. :(

Comment: I tried that and it came up with the error message '#1111 invalid use of group function'. That was my first attempt

Comment: I proposed another solution, does that work for you?

Comment: Jonny - thanks for the updated code but I am getting error message '#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias'

Comment: Like SUB_Q  :)

Very similar to mine Johnny and in fairness you go there first but missed the alias for the Sub Query.

Comment: Yeah, you can't wrap an aggregate function in an aggregate function. But I think subqueries are to be avoided whenever possible. Gordon got it right.